# Selecting values based on value in another column with one being NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table setup

```
Acc  Currency  Alias
1    NULL      A
1    USD       B
1    EUR       C
```

I want to extract the alias by giving the input as `Acc`. The `Currency` and `Acc` are joined to another table.

It should work as follows -

```
If acc = 1 and currency is USD then B, if EUR then C, if null then A
```

Can someone help with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try to write **any** SQL yourself?

```
SELECT ...
FROM otherTable ot
(INNER) JOIN thisTable tt
ON ot.Acc = tt.Acc AND ot.Currency = tt.Currency 
...
```

Comment: Yes I have...below is a sort of pseudo e.g, but the problem I have is the currency can be NULL sometimes and I have to extract the alias based on the logic.


select  s.Alias from 
t1 
inner join t2
on t1.Acc = t2.acc
where 
and t1.[currency] = t2.[currency]


the values in currency may change...and can be null...

Lets say t2 has currency as YEN, then I want alias A.

Comment: Just to clarify

If currency in table 2 matches table 1 then get the corresponding alias. If it doesnt then get the alias for NULL.

Comment: There are two options for JOIN on NULL values - LEFT OUTER JOIN (may be MSSQL specific) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758409/sql-join-on-null-values

Answer (score 0):

Matching on NULL explicitly

```
SELECT *
  FROM othertbl o
  JOIN thistbl t on o.acc = t.acc
                and (o.currency = t.currency or o.currency is null AND t.currency is null)
```

Or in your case, using the NULL currency from `thistbl` as a fallback

```
 SELECT ...
   FROM othertbl o
   JOIN thistbl t on o.acc = t.acc and o.currency = t.currency
  UNION ALL
 SELECT ...
   FROM othertbl o
   JOIN thistbl t on o.acc = t.acc and t.currency IS NULL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (select *
                      from thistbl t2
                     where o.acc = t2.acc and o.currency = t2.currency)
```