# LINQ Join on a Nullable key

Tags: c#, linq

The LINQ `Join()` method with `Nullable<int>` for `TKey` skips over null key matches.  What am I missing in the documentation?  I know that I can switch to `SelectMany()`, I'm just curious why this equality operation works like SQL and not like C# since as near as I can tell, the `EqualityComparer<int?>.Default` works exactly like I would expect it to for null values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class dt
{
   public int? Id;
   public string Data;
}

public class JoinTest
{
    public static int Main(string [] args)
    {
        var a = new List<dt>
        {
            new dt { Id = null, Data = "null" },
            new dt { Id = 1, Data = "1" },
            new dt { Id = 2, Data = "2" }
        };

        var b = new List<dt>
        {
            new dt { Id = null, Data = "NULL" },
            new dt { Id = 2, Data = "two" },
            new dt { Id = 3, Data = "three" }
        };

        //Join with null elements
        var c = a.Join( b,
            dtA => dtA.Id,
            dtB => dtB.Id,
            (dtA, dtB) => new { aData = dtA.Data, bData = dtB.Data } ).ToList();
        // Output:
        // 2 two
        foreach ( var aC in c )
            Console.WriteLine( aC.aData + " " + aC.bData );
        Console.WriteLine( " " );

        //Join with null elements converted to zero
        c = a.Join( b,
            dtA => dtA.Id.GetValueOrDefault(),
            dtB => dtB.Id.GetValueOrDefault(),
            (dtA, dtB) => new { aData = dtA.Data, bData = dtB.Data } ).ToList();

        // Output:
        // null NULL
        // 2 two
        foreach ( var aC in c )
            Console.WriteLine( aC.aData + " " + aC.bData );

        Console.WriteLine( EqualityComparer<int?>.Default.Equals( a[0].Id, b[0].Id ) );
        Console.WriteLine( EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals( a[0].Id, b[0].Id ) );
        Console.WriteLine( a[0].Id.Equals( b[0].Id ) );

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) uses `JoinIterator` (private class) to iterate over matching elements. `JoinIterator` uses [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) for creating lookups of sequence keys:

```
internal static Lookup<TKey, TElement> CreateForJoin(
    IEnumerable<TElement> source, 
    Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, 
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    Lookup<TKey, TElement> lookup = new Lookup<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
    foreach (TElement local in source)
    {
        TKey key = keySelector(local);
        if (key != null) // <--- Here
        {
            lookup.GetGrouping(key, true).Add(local);
        }
    }
    return lookup;
}
```

Interesting part here is skipping keys which are `null`. That's why without providing default value you have only one match.

---

Looks like I found the reason of such behavior. Lookup uses default EqualityComparer, which will return `0` both for key which is `null` and key which is `0`:

```
int? keyA = 0;
var comparer = EqualityComparer<int?>.Default;
int hashA = comparer.GetHashCode(keyA) & 0x7fffffff; // from Lookup class
int? keyB = null;
int hashB = comparer.GetHashCode(keyB) & 0x7fffffff;
Console.WriteLine(hashA); // 0
Console.WriteLine(hashB); // 0
```

Possibly nulls skipped to avoid matching `null` and `0` keys.

Comment: Did I miss that in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: @ryancerium just checked msdn, looks like there is no mention of this behavior. But I'm looking on sources with Reflector and see this implementation..

Comment: That seems like a fairly serious omission in the documentation to me.  Thanks for looking into that for me.

Comment: I doubt that is the reason for this behavior.  What else would a null value hash to?  If the values compared were null, the hash wouldn't even be considered anyway.

Comment: @JeffMercado maybe to 42 :) Anyway, they even give no chance to treat null keys manually. If you will pass your own comparer, it even will not be called for null keys (see code above). I think Microsoft should add remark about this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I think it's done that way to match the behavior of databases where [you can't join on null keys, they are just ignored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409(v=sql.105).aspx).  [There are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758409/sql-join-on-null-values) to get past this limitation which unfortunately can't be written in LINQ.

You'll have to write your query in such a way that none of the keys are actually null.  You can do that simply by wrapping the value in another object that can be compared for equality (e.g., a tuple or anonymous object).

```
//Join with null elements
var c = a.Join( b,
    dtA => Tuple.Create(dtA.Id),
    dtB => Tuple.Create(dtB.Id),
    (dtA, dtB) => new { aData = dtA.Data, bData = dtB.Data } ).ToList();
```

Comment: Oops, I guess I misread your question. I thought you were asking why it behaved that way, not why the LINQ-to-Objects implementation behaved like LINQ-to-Entities/-SQL implementations. The answer for that, consistency.